# Problems with mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to read some data from a form and then use them using php. I use only mysqli in my php file but I get some warnings and i don't understand why. Here is some code:

```
<?php

// Connects to your Database
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "database");

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$all_string = $_GET['name'];

if($all_string == NULL) exit("Nothing is written\n");

echo "$all_string"."<br/>";

$tok = strtok($all_string, ",");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Suggrammata";
/*line 22*/$results = mysqli_query($sql, $con);

/*line 24*/while($is = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
.
.
.
?>
```

Here are the warnings:

```
Warning:
mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in 
/var/www/php_anazhthshs/euresh_suggrammatwn_aplh.php on line 22 

Warning: 
mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given 
in/var/www/php_anazhthshs/euresh_suggrammatwn_aplh.php on line 24
```

Can you help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mixed up params in mysqli_query call

Answer (score 3):

Arguments must be inverted.

```
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

[mysqli_query()](http://php.net//manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: Something as simple as this should be answered in a comment, and then the question voted to close as a typo - you don't have close-vote powers yet, but just so you know ;)

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol : Ok thanks